# Bochs 2.6.11 & Android & RAM Memory

Tags: android, crash, sdl, ram, bochs

I am running the Bochs 2.6.11 от Android. If I set RAM More than (>) 2048 MB (2GB) Bochs crashes into the menu after the SDL logo. But I have got 4 GB RAM free.
Bochsrc:

```
romimage: file=/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/net.sourceforge.bochs/files/BIOS-bochs-latest

vgaromimage: file=VGABIOS-lgpl-latest-cirrus

cpu: model=corei7_haswell_4770

vga: extension=cirrus, update_freq=15

pci: enabled=1, chipset=i440fx, slot1=cirrus, slot2=ne2k

ne2k: mac=b0:c4:20:00:00:00, ethmod=slirp, script=""

ata0: enabled=1, ioaddr1=0x1f0, ioaddr2=0x3f0, irq=14

ata1: enabled=1, ioaddr1=0x170, ioaddr2=0x370, irq=15

ata0-master: type=disk, path="/storage/emulated/0/duck/fbchs/MicroXP_Anatomica/C2-7111-16-63.img"

boot: disk

megs: 3072

sound: waveoutdrv=sdl

speaker: enabled=1, mode=sound

mouse: enabled=1

clock: sync=none, time0=local

debug: action=ignore

info: action=ignore

error: action=ignore

panic: action=report

log: bochsout.txt
```

Comment: Bochs emulates an 32bit x86 system. 2GB is a magic border for 32bit systems, 4GB the final border. 2GB seems to be the limit for Bochs: https://github.com/ipxe/bochs/blob/master/.bochsrc#L1263

Comment: @Robert but for example Windows XP supports more than 3 gb (≈4gb). Also, how to fix it?

Comment: It seems like Bochs was designed for max 2GB RAM so there is no "fix". Take it as it is and live with it or try to find a different software.

Comment: Wait, can recompiling help me? When yes, than say limit containing file name @Robert

Comment: @Robert if apk editing can help just type /path/to/file:line:symbol